# Fancy jQuery Tags Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add a jQuery/Javascript based selector type of element in my application. The idea is that a user is presented with say 50 tags inside a textarea, but instead of just selecting a tag word and removing it, there is an X alongside that removes the tag from the list and there is a textbox where a new word can be added. Hope this makes sense.

I would like to ask, is there a ready made open source solution for this ?

Comment: no, not really, tags is mostly like an example, it's sort of like a list of things in a text area, each one below its previous one. I'm looking for a way to make selection from a list of words easier for the user.

Comment: You may be looking for something like this: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ although it is slightly off-topic.

Comment: The multiple selection seems rather close to what i want. Ideally, i would want these tags placed one on top of the other and starting out selected. I can probably customize this, have to take a closer look. Btw, it's part of programming a Tags selector, so i wouldn't really think it's off topic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually found one which seems to do the trick :

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a project recently and this plugin worked very nicely for me:
http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

It does "x" to delete, backspace to delete, callback on adding and removing tags, autocomplete and other nice features.